Cook's distance in logistic
I am confused about which formula for Cook's distance is correct, especially in the context of logistic regression, as I’ve found two different expressions.
The first formula is: $$CD_i=\frac{rp_i^2 h_{ii}}{(k+1)(1-h_{ii})^2},$$ where $k$ is number of parameters, $rp_i$ be Pearson residual and $h_{ii}$ is the leverage of the $i$’th observation.
The second formula is: $$D_i = \frac{rp_i^2}{k \cdot \text{MSE}} \cdot \frac{h_{ii}}{(1 - h_{ii})^2}$$
How do these two formulas relate to each other? Are they equivalent, and how should I interpret the differences between them specifically in the context of logistic regression?
